# OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier offset length for markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, offset, overlapping, markerspiderfier

**Background**
I use google maps together with clustermarkererplus to display various markertypes with infobubbles on a map. To deal with markers with exactly the same coordinate (or very close) an offset is generated for the markers that overlap by using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier (OMS). Searching for an answer to this has so far only led me to adjustment of the thickness of the offset lines.

**Problem**
When there are many markers the offset given by the OMS is too small.

**Questions**

- How can I increase the offset (leg length)?
- Can it be dependent on if the number of markers separated by the OMS is more than a certain value?

**Example (to show the effect)**
[Visualisation of what I want to do, increase offset (leg length)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Qzi.png)

**Code**
Documentation of OMS is available at: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier
`//Options I use`
    `options = {keepSpiderfied:true};`

`//Creation of the OMS`
    `new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, options);`

`//Click listener`
    `oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {`
     `//Code for showing infowindows`
    `});`

`//Adding marker`
    `oms.addMarker(marker);`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: looks to me like you want: `circleSpiralSwitchover` (default: 9), "This is the lowest number of markers that will be fanned out into a spiral instead of a circle. Set this to 0 to always get spirals, or Infinity for all circles.".  But you haven't provided an example so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: @geocodezip , I have now changed my example to a picture and hopefully it is easier to see in that one what offset I want to increase. I want the markers further out from the center no matter if a spiral or a circle is generated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier has adjustable offset (leg length) by specifying two different options:**

1. circleFootSeparation: "default:23" (Offset from the center of the circle)
2. spiralLengthFactor:"default:4" (Value proportional to the offset from the spiral center)

**Angular separation can also be adjusted for the spiral**
spiralFootSeparation:"default:26"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier, so just did some research and found this tutorial. It also include '*legWeight*' which determine the thickness of the lines joining spiderfied markers to their original locations.

Here's the link for Overlapping Marker Spiderfier: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

I hope it might help you.